# Site Visits (Site Analytics) always return Zero SharePoint Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, web-analytics, site-usage

I have a Communication Sites and Team Sites in my SP 2019 farm.

**Problem:**

**Communication Site** - It does **not showing Site visits (Always return Zero)** but in the New Items has the value in Site Analytics also Popularity Trends returns the some valid data. Its subsite also showing number of Site visits.so problem is only raising on root site collection

**Team Site** - It was working fine. It **shows number of Site visits** and New Items in Site Analytics

Anyone help me on this!!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the communication has been crawled in search service application.

Go to search service application> find the relative content source crawl logs to find if the communication site has been crawled successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @julie_MSFT. Yes it is crawled and site Url is in the crawl log

Comment: Im facing same issue like this issue - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271232/site-usage-shows-0-but-trending-shows-views-being-tracked-in-sharepoint-2019